# How do I change Android Studio editor appearance?

Tags: android, android-studio, themes

I started learning Java in BlueJ and BlueJ has a great layout for code where you have a background color for each "method".

BlueJ Layout Picture:

[image: BlueJ Layout Picture]

Android Studio Layout Picture:

[image: Android Studio Layout Picture]

Comment: android studio plugins didnt provide blue j plugins. may be you can customize your self in android studio Preferences

Answer (score 2):

Go to settings >> Editor >> Color & Fonts >> Java

there are many options to explore there, not just in java. just try it